# Unable to create VPC security group with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create an EC2 server with this setup. `plan` does not complain about anything, but when running `apply` I get this error:

```
* aws_instance.example: Failed to update vpc_security_group_ids 
on "i-04b724c52ac598fd8", which does not contain a primary network interface
```

Any idea what might be wrong?
I'm using Terraform v0.9.6

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami                    = "ami-40d28157"
  instance_type          = "m3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]

  tags {
    Name = "up-and-running"
  }

}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance-1"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate which VPC your security group is created in, using `vpc_id` param for security group resource. It must point to the same VPC, in which you are creating your ec2 instance:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance-1"
  vpc_id = "${var.your_vpc_id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```